# Regex for replacing commas only within square brackets

Tags: r, regex, pcre

I have a text file and it contains comma separated strings.  But some of the strings separated by commas are of the form `[*,*,*,...]`.  So for example:

"Hello", "Goodbye", ["Yes", "No", "Maybe], "Indeed", ["Why", "What"]

I want to be able to parse the file to replace only commas within square brackets with a semicolon.  There can be any number of brackets and any number of commas within the brackets.

I tried using this code in R but its not working as planned, some commas outside my brackets are being replaced:

```r
repeat{
          tmp <- gsub("(\\[.*\\K),(?=.*\\])", ";", tmp, perl = TRUE) # replace last comma found within braces with semicolon
          if (sum(grepl("(\\[.*\\K),(?=.*\\])", tmp, perl = TRUE)) == 0) {  # repeat until no more commas found
            break
          }
        }
```

Can anyone help with regex that can solve this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Is this a single string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace all commas inside square brackets with semi-colons, you may use

```
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|\\[)[^][,]*\\K,", ";", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPHDcU/1). The regex above does not check for the closing `]` though. If it is required, use

```
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|\\[)[^][,]*\\K,(?=[^][]*])", ";", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPHDcU/2)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\[)` - end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) a `[` (`\[`)
- `[^][,]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and a `]`
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all the text matched so far
- `,` - a comma
- `(?=[^][]*])` - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and a `]` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thank you - this worked perfectly - as a quick follow up, I also wondered what the change would be to the regex string if I were dealing with curly brackets ({}) instead of square ([])

Comment: @Keith Replace each literal `[` with `{` and `]` with `}`, `"(?:\\G(?!^)|\\{)[^{},]*\\K,(?=[^{}]*})"`

Comment: @Keith Well, it would be different with `()`. You would need to escape both.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!  Also I don't think its a straight like for like replacement in the original solution - played around and came to this answer for round brackets https://regex101.com/r/EPHDcU/3